# how to properly use np.subtract's broadcast

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have 2 matrices, the shape of the first one is (2,64) and the shape of the second one is (2,256,64), now I want to do np.subtract between this 2 matrices, because `np.subtract(matrix1, matrix2)` cannot broadcast automatically, what I did is below

```
step_1 = np.subtract(matrix1[0], matrix2[0]).shape  ## shape is (256,64)
step_2 = np.subtract(matrix1[1], matrix2[1]).shape  ## shape is (256,64)
res = np.array([step_1, step_2]) ## shape is (2,256,64)
```

or

```
res = np.array([np.subtract(matrix1[i], matrix2[i]) for i in range(2)]) ## shape is (2,256,64)
```

Can I do something like this only using np.subtract(By setting some kinds of parameters) in a single step to get the same answer, (or using other technique like np.swapaxes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a new axis using `None` (which is an alias for [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis)) to line them up directly:

```
matrix_1[:, None, :] - matrix2
```

Unless you want to use some of the features of an explicit call to [`np.subtract`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html), the minus operator (`-`) is cleaner.

Another alternative is to get the same view with [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html):

```
np.expand_dims(matrix1, 1) - matrix2
```

You can also [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
matrix1.reshape(matrix1.shape[0], 1, *matrix1.shape[1:]) - matrix2
```

The solution you propose with [`swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.swapaxes.html) is a bit drastic, but will work:

```
(matrix1 - matrix2.swapaxes(0, 1)).swapaxes(0, 1)
```

The final `swapaxes` on the result is necessary to get the original shape back. You can achieve similar results with [`transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html):

```
(matrix1 - matrix2.transpose(1, 0, 2)).swapaxes(1, 0, 2)
```

Comment: @Jasper. I've added some more approaches